# Gambler's ruin and Markov Chain, coin toss and stakes

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, gambling

I'm considering a classical problem about Markov Chains:

A gambler has $£8$ and wishes to get to $£10$. A coin is tossed repeatedly : if it comes down tails, the gambler loses his stake, and if it comes down heads, his stake is return and he wins an amount equal to it. He decides to follow a simple strategy: if he has less than $£5$, he stakes everything, if he has more, he stakes just enough to get $£10$ if he wins.

I let $X_n$ be the gambler's capital after the $n$th coin toss (in $£$).
I've already worked out some results, played along with the situation, the state space is limited $\lbrace0,2,4,6,8,10\rbrace$ and we can write a transition matrix

$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
1/2&0&1/2&0&0&0\\
1/2&0&0&0&1/2&0\\
0&1/2&0&0&0&1/2\\
0&0&0&1/2&0&1/2\\
0&0&0&0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

I'm trying to find out about the distribution of the whole sequence $X_0,X_1,...$ conditional on the event that he reaches $£10$ at some point.

I've tried an easy example such as $\mathbb{P}(X_1=10 | X_n=10$ for some $n\geq1,[X_0=8])$ but I don't get anywhere... Do you have an idea?

Any help would be amazing, thank you!

Comment: Yes, I've got a $6$x$6$ transition matrix (with $0,1,1/2$ in various positions), only even values are possible for the sequence.

Comment: Right, I've edited with the matrix and state space.

Comment: Have you been taught the definition of (i) *martingales*, (ii) *h-transforms*, and how to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is a Markov chain on the state space $\{2,4,6,8,10\}$ with transitions:

- $8\to6$ and $8\to10$ with probabilities $\frac38$ and $\frac58$ respectively
- $6\to2$ and $6\to10$ with probabilities $\frac16$ and $\frac56$ respectively
- $2\to4$ and $4\to8$ both with probability $1$.